# how to config multiple datasource/ebean for play project

Tags: playframework

My play project is created with play framework 2.4. I want to configure two datasouroces for it, one for test purpose, one for production.

### test datasource

```
db.test.driver=org.h2.Driver<br>
db.test.url="jdbc:h2:mem:test;MODE=MYSQL;MVCC=false;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1"
```

### production datasource

```
  db.mysql.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
  db.mysql.url="jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/db"
  db.mysql.user=root
  db.mysql.password=root
```

I also configure Ebean server for this two datasource and set the default Ebean datasource as 'test'.

```
   ebean.test=["xx.*"]
   ebean.mysql=["xx.*"]
   ebeanconfig.datasource.default=test
```

But when i run my unit test(activator test), got error:

> *[PersistenceException: The default EbeanServer has not been defined? This is normally set via the ebean.datasource.default property.
>   Otherwise it should be registered programatically via
>   registerServer()]*

I also tried to use property **ebean.datasource.default=test** to set the default Ebean datasource, but still failed.

Any configuration error for me? I'm really struggle for this...

Answer (score 5):

Change the property `ebean.datasource.default` to `play.ebean.defaultDatasource`, to set/override the default ebean datasource. I made a pull request in the java documentation part ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can have different modes of running your play application for having dev,staging and prod environments such as -
play -Dmode=dev/staging/prod run

Comment: thanks for the reply, but this doesn't resolve my problem. I have two db sources defined in the cofig file, play complains there's no default db source.

Comment: Can you try with config as-

db.default.driver=""
db.default.url=""

ebean.default = "models.*"

You may choose to point default db to test datasource.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, i have two conf files, one configured with 'test' datasource and another file configured with "production" source. And run them with -Dconfig.file parameter specified.